# PHP breaks grunt build (htmlmin)

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Using php code breaks the grunt build script of a yeoman generated project. Specifically the htmlmin task breaks.
Is there a way to get this to work? A workaround I recently used was commenting out and later uncommenting php blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grunt-contrib-html task should only be run on vanilla HTML.

---

*Though feel free to open a ticket on [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/issues) for PHP tag support.*

Comment: Thanks. Bu what if I don’t need to minify my html? Is there a way to omit the htmlmin task completely? Or will usemin etc. also break?

Comment: Just ignore the files you don't want run through html. Read the grunt docs.

Comment: That doesnt’t help because I actually want to run rev and usemin tasks on that file. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Then use the copy task to copy the files to where the htmlmin task would have placed them.

Comment: Thanks so much! Finally I got everything I need for my workflow.